# Can you explain why Entity Framework is doing this?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I was doing a project/tutorial and I have a two classes that are related to the migration in question. First in the `Customer` class and then the `MembershipType` class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubcribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
    public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class MembershipType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public short SignUpFee { get; set; }
    public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
    public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
}
```

When I do a migration it creates this

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Customers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 255, nullable: false),
                IsSubcribedToNewsletter = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                MembershipTypeId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                MembershipTypeId = table.Column<byte>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Customers", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Customers_MembershipTypes_MembershipTypeId1",
                    column: x => x.MembershipTypeId1,
                    principalTable: "MembershipTypes",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Customers_MembershipTypeId1",
            table: "Customers",
            column: "MembershipTypeId1");
    }
```

Where is the `MembershipTypeId1` coming from?

I was following a tutorial and this isn't explained at all. I am also using a new .NET version so its making it even harder for me to figure out the why and how to correct it based on what I am seeing.

`MembershipTypeId1` should represent an object `MembershipType` from the other class. I think this is the problem but I am not sure why it it is converting it to `MembershipTypeId1`. Also how would you use this in a table to represent an object. Normally I would just use the id and do a join so I am not sure why they are doing it this way or what is the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `byte MembershipTypeId` in your `Customer` class, presumably as the foreign key column:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .....
    public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
           ****
}
```

Unfortunately, the datatype doesn't match the primary key of `MembershipType`, which is defined as int:

```
public class MembershipType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
           ***
    ....
}
```

Therefore, EF will introduce it's own generated FK column `MembershipType1` with the correct datatype.

I'm pretty sure if you fix this "flaw"; then EF won't create its own separate `MembershipType1` column anymore, but it would use your `MembershipType` column instead:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubcribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
    // make it "INT", since PK on MembershipType is INT        
    public int MembershipTypeId { get; set; }  
}
```